# is it possible to get the values of read command from script when call in nohup mode

Tags: shell-script

Ex. I have one script Test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "/n read the value"
read info

if [ "$info" = 1 ];
then
echo "yes"
else
echo "no"
fi
```

I want to call Test.sh script from another script (test2.sh) in nohup mode. Is there any way i can provide the value to "read info" by passing with arguments/ any other way.

test2.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
Test.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, by [passing it on standard input](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/InputAndOutput). One way of doing that is a pipe (demonstrating how to reverse two lines):

```
$ cat > test.sh <<'EOF'
> #!/bin/sh
> read -r first
> read -r second
> printf '%s\n' "$second" "$first"
> EOF
$ chmod u+x test.sh 
$ printf '%s\n' foo bar | nohup ./test.sh
nohup: appending output to 'nohup.out'
$ cat nohup.out 
bar
foo
```

Comment: & if we have multiple read command in the script then how can we provide the values ?

Comment: Multiple lines. Each `read` will consume one "line", by default terminated with `\n`. See `help read`.

Comment: I did't get it. My question is if 2 read commands in the script & i have to run in nohup mode then  how can i give values using echo. Eg. script:#!/bin/sh

echo "/n read the value1"
read info1

echo "/n read the value2"
read info2


echo "$info1 $info2">>log.txt